# When I hide some div elements, and fadeIn other div elements in their place, the divs fading in appear to "jump"?

Tags: jquery, css

The action I am talking about can be [recreated here](http://mixtape.meteor.com).

Search for a video using the search bar and then hit the `Play` button down below. You will see that the player "jumps" up to collect its spot.

How do I resolve that behaviour such that it smoothly fades in at that location?

The following is the code that is run to perform the toggle:

```
    /*The elements that get hidden are below*/
    $("#playlist").css('display','none');
    $("#button_control").hide();
    $("#search-group").hide();
    $("#playlist_container").hide();

    /*The element that becomes visible (AND JUMPS!) below*/
    $("#player-list_container").fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: a link to your site does a future reader no good should that site change. please set up a fiddle for a working example

Comment: Will do, thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a delay, so that it has time for the other elements to get out of the way, thus appearing in the right spot.

```
$("#player-list_container").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to make that element invisible by using CSS 'visibility' - 'hidden', not 'display' - 'none'. It will make that element invisible, but element will stay on it's place.